# Gmail warning about unencrypted email sent from Exchange 2013

Tags: ssl, exchange-2013, gmail

I've been reading, researching but it's still not clear to me.

All emails that are sent from the Exchange server from our company, whether through OWA or Outlook, Gmail indicates that they are not encrypted, like in the image [Gmail warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YotfV.jpg).

How do I configure them to be encrypted with standard TLS.

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK Exchange 2013 uses opportunistic TLS by default. However, we can't say whether your Exchange sends mail to Gmail directly or not. Please add the full `Received` headers of the message.

Comment: Hi. Would you mind to mark the helpful reply as a best answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Would you get the similar error when you send email to outlook account?

You could encrypt all outgoing emails from Outlook Trust Center, please refer to this article "[Encrypt email messages](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/encrypt-email-messages-373339cb-bf1a-4509-b296-802a39d801dc?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)" to get more details.

Comment: Hi, 

I read the link, but what about the emails sent from OWA?
To a Outlook account i recived in the spam folder, doesnt says anything about unencrypted.

BTW, i got a 9/10 score on mail-tester.com if this help. 
Thank you.

Comment: You still cansend encrypted emails via outlook. Check the Microsoft's document.https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/encrypt-messages-by-using-s-mime-in-outlook-web-app-2e57e4bd-4cc2-4531-9a39-426e7c873e26

Comment: Hi, is there any update?

Comment: How's everything going? I'd appreciate it if you choose the most helpful post above and mark it as the best answer, this will make answer searching in the forum easier and be beneficial to other community members as well. Thanks!